# The moment of inertia of a rigid hemisphere about diameter of a base is (a) $Ma^2/5$ (b) $Ma^2/2$ (c) $2Ma^2/5$ (d) More information needed

Tags: mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

While solving question,

The moment of inertia of a rigid hemisphere of mass $M$ and radius $a$ about a diameter of a base is

(a) $Ma^2/5$ (b) $Ma^2/2$ (c) $2Ma^2/5$ (d) More information needed ?

I know that moment of inertia of rigid sphere of mass $M$ and radius $a$ about a diameter of a base is $2Ma^2/5,$ So, I guess that

It should be same for hemisphere because now $M$ is mass of hemisphere not total mass of sphere? Am I right? Thanks

Comment: You should do the integral to find out. Do you know how to set it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the axis of rotation is the symmetry axis (from center of base, orthogonal to the tip of the hemisphere), then 
I = 2/5 m a² .

So your assumption is right.
Best regards

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).